# android alarm sound not working

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have created an app where a user can insert various subjects and their day of exam.my app provides a time span for each subjects stored in database. when time allocated for each subject reaches,an alarm should play along with a notification.notification is coming properly,but alarm sound is not playing.please help me.

My alarm manager class is :

```
public class AlarmManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

sampleDatabase appdb;
SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
Cursor cursor;
int today,prev;
Intent in;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon , "Yahrzeit" , System.currentTimeMillis());
    in = new Intent(context,FirstAppActivity.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, in, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "ALERT!!!!", "Time Over" , contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    appdb = new sampleDatabase(context);
    sqldb = appdb.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = sqldb.query(sampleDatabase.TABLE_SEC, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    today = (int)(cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000);
    Log.e("Naga","Alarm");
    Log.e("today",Integer.toString(today));
    prev = 0;
    cursor.moveToPrevious();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int dbdate = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(sampleDatabase.ALARMSET));
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(sampleDatabase.ROW_ID));
        Log.e("dbdate",Integer.toString(dbdate));
        if((dbdate<=today)&&(dbdate>prev))
        {
            manger.cancelAll();
            manger.notify(1, notification);
            sqldb.execSQL("DELETE from " + sampleDatabase.TABLE + " where " + sampleDatabase.ROW_ID + "=" + id);
            sqldb.execSQL("DELETE from "+sampleDatabase.TABLE_SEC + " where " + sampleDatabase.ROW_ID + "=" + id);

        }
        prev = dbdate;
    }
    cursor.close();
    sqldb.close();

}
```

code which i used to call this alarm manager is like this:

```
 alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.nagainfo.firstAp.AlarmManager.class);
                sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext() , 0 , alarmintent , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);            
                am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.cancel(sender);

                alarmintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.nagainfo.firstAp.AlarmManager.class);
                //alarmintent.putExtra("note","Hebrew");
                sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext() , 0 , alarmintent , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
                am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmtime, 60000, sender);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified to use sound. Use this :

```
notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

If you do not want the vibrate remove it. The point is you have to bit wise OR them. So, if you want lights also -

```
notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND|Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone are using NotificationCompat.Builder, you can use:

```
    Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notifyBuilder.setSound(sound);
```